# WP already installed is asking to install

Tags: upgrade, installation

Hey guys, i did a mistake on a wp site, i uploaded a wrong wp-config.php file on the server during a 3.1 update, saw the mistake, recreated a good one with the good infos, uploaded the file and didnt get back the site! Now wordpress askes me to install it! Which i dont want to, cos it's all already installed. I backuped the database and checked it online, it's all fine, with for exemple the good infos for 'home' and 'url' tables.

If anyone knows what's going on (the install question) and i could get it back, it'd be more than welcome (am kinda stressed a lot now).

Second question, if i do reinstall it, will it crash the existing datas in the database?

EDIT: i checked the english version which is on the same database on the same server, site.com/en, it works fine.

Comment: make sure that the config file is named wp-config.php

Comment: I realize its 2018 so this is more for new ppl that run across this, if your site is prompting to reinstall WP, you've left the install scripts in place and they should not be there if this is a production site.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Got it back, the `$table_prefix` line was wrong in my wp-config.php. Fiu.

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was fixing the `DB_NAME` value in wp-config.php

Comment: If WP can't find the database, it makes sense it asks you to reinstall. This solution worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

In one case i had, i replaced the wp-config.php file and forgot to edit the database prefix configuration to my database prefix.