# WordPress asks to install, but is already installed?

Tags: mysql, local-installation, xampp, mac

I know this has been resolved many times including [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10451/wp-already-installed-is-asking-to-install), but I can't figure this out in my case.

I've been using XAMPP for Mac on Mojave and recently, I updated it to the latest version of - [7.3.1](https://www.apachefriends.org/xampp-files/7.3.1/xampp-osx-7.3.1-0-installer.dmg).

Anyway all of my WP local instances stopped working, no matter if I go to `localhost/template1` or `localhost/template2`. WordPress always asks to install, but after picking language and then my login I'm getting to a page with countless errors saying `[Table 'wp_users' already exists]`, `[Table 'wp_usermeta' already exists]` and so forth.

I've checked `wp-config.php` for every project and the data there seems right, `DB_USER`, `DB_NAME`, `DB_PASSWORD`, `DB_HOST`,`DB_CHARSET`, `WPLANG` are correct. `$table_prefix` too (default "_wp").

Looks like WP recognises the database after all, upon installation, how can I debug this? Maybe it's related to upgrading PHP and MySQL version?

Thanks!

Comment: You can check $table_prefix  = 'wp_';   in wp-config.php. If if is different from your database table, then it will ask you to install WordPress again.

Comment: I always use default prefix, so "_wp", is there anything else I could check?

Comment: Did you find out what was happening? I'm having the same issue and can't find anything online.